# Find and replace missing values in List in R

Tags: r, replace

I need answers on this topic. I have several files in a folder which I have imported to R using:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt") 

myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim)
```

The resulting files are on the workspace stored as `List[110]`. So they are 110 files in the list. Each files has several different columns and rows.

My question: I would like to find and replace -999.99M with `NA`; Find 'T','C','A','F' and 'Y', delete them from all the 110 files.

Answer (score 2):

+1 for using `lapply` to put all your datasets in a list.

If I've understood you correctly, you can do the following for the replacement:

```
myfiles <- lapply(myfiles, function(df)
                  data.frame(lapply(df, function(x) {
                             if(is.numeric(x))
                                 x[x == -999.99] <- NA
                             else x[x %in% c('T','C','A','F','Y')] <- NA
                             x
                  })
           )
```